# Tradingview Lightweight candlestick charts price depth

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api, candlestick-chart, lightweight-charts

I'm building a candlestick chart with preset of price data. By default it is set to two decimals `0.01` of price. However my price data ranges way past from 0.01 to 0.0000002 etc. I'm trying to implement `priceFormat` property but it doesn't work. Thank you

Here's my code and chart data

```
const log = console.log;

const chartProperties = {
    width:1200,
    height:600,
    timeScale:{
        timeVisible:true,
        secondsVisible:false,
    },
    priceFormat: {
        type: 'price',
        precision: 6,
        minMove: 0.000001,
    },
}

const domElement = document.getElementById('chart');
const chart = LightweightCharts.createChart(domElement,chartProperties);
const candleSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries();

fetch(`http://localhost:8888/chart/dataset.txt`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        const cdata = data.map(d => {
            return {time:d[0]/1000,open:parseFloat(d[1]),high:parseFloat(d[2]),low:parseFloat(d[3]),close:parseFloat(d[4])}
        });
        candleSeries.setData(cdata);
    })
    .catch(err => log(err));
```

```
[
[1640060100000,"0.004","0.008","0.002","0.0055",1640060159999],[1640060160000,"0.0055","0.008","0.002","0.005",1640060219999],[1640078220000,"0.005","0.008","0.002","0.0045",1640078279000],[1640078280000,"0.0045","0.0065","0.0043","0.0058",1640078339000]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/discussions/697:

To change format of your series' data you need to override [price format](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/SeriesOptionsCommon#priceformat) for your series by changing/applying options.

For example, if you'd like to show 6 digits after a comma you can use the following options:

```js
series.applyOptions({
    priceFormat: {
        type: 'price',
        precision: 6,
        minMove: 0.000001,
    },
});
```

Also, you can look at [this test case](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/blob/b75839519282295ded1b8a6b8bae9a4686f45de1/tests/e2e/graphics/test-cases/initial-options/price-format.js) for more complete example.